# Why does a Bootstrap 3 date input look different in Firefox compared to Chrome?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

Would anyone happen to know why there is a difference between the appearance of a Bootstrap 3 date picker input in Mozilla Firefox (as of version 69.0.1)  and Google Chrome (version 77.0.3865.120)?

Is it possible to fix the appearance and if so, how could I fix this? The problem is that the value tries to stick to the bottom of any given date input in Firefox.

In Google Chrome:

[image: Chrome sample date input]

In Mozilla Firefox:

[image: Firefox sample date input]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sampleInput">Sample input</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="sampleInput" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omk5db4h/)

Comment: It appears to be set by `line-height: 34px` in a media query (`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {}`) of an inline style. It looks to be a bug in Firefox, as the comment for that section mentions it's only supposed to apply to iOS Mobile Safari.

Comment: Bud of mine found a fix for the problem [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1503427#c14).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tyler mentions in the comments, this is caused by the media query

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
```

in bootstrap.min.css. This has the `-webkit-` prefix, so it is designed to be used only in Webkit based browsers, but the problem is that Firefox has a setting that makes it process the `-webkit-` prefix too, which causes this issue.

To switch this feature off, go to **about:config** in Firefox and set either **layout.css.prefixes.webkit** or **layout.css.prefixes.device-pixel-ratio-webkit** to **false**. (Which one of those two will work, seems to depend on the version of Firefox.)

Or if you don't want your users to go changing advanced settings in Firefox, you can undo the Bootstrap CSS by setting the line-height for those inputs back to `normal` in your own CSS.

```css
input[type=date].form-control,input[type=datetime-local].form-control,input[type=month].form-control,input[type=time].form-control {
  line-height:normal;
}
```

Comment: But what if a user is not aware of this issue? I would need code for the application to still be correctly visible even when their settings would be different? I should not need to be required to instruct/demand users of my app have certain browser settings on now would I?

Comment: Well, you can reset the line-height to `normal`, and then maybe use some padding to make it come out the way you want in all browsers.

Comment: That's what I found in a solution as well. I also took a peek at the setting you described above and apparently there's no record for **prefixes.webkit**.

Comment: I too am missing such a property in about:config (running FF 69.0.2)

Comment: Sorry; apparently there are different settings for different versions of Firefox. layout.css.prefixes.webkit works on my machine in FF 60ESR, but for FF 71 Nightly I need to change layout.css.prefixes.device-pixel-ratio-webkit. I updated my answer now.